# Resize view inside container view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, container-view

I am using Storyboards in Xcode 4.6 and I just found out about container views. My container view is displaying a UITableView.

The UITableView and its cells take up the entire width of the screen but the container view is slightly smaller because I want the container view to display a "mini" version of the UITableView.

Unfortunately the container view doesn't auto resize whatever view is in it and the cells of the table are full size.

How can I scale down the UITableView to fit the container view?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Container view", is this a ContainerView Controller ? if so, why dont just resize the container view ? normally, the content must be at least equal or less than the container's frame.

Comment: According to Xcode, a Container View seems to be just another view controller (http://cl.ly/OL4q). The content, the UITableView, is as large as the whole screen (minus status bar) but the Container View is only 280x132 and is centred horizontally. It doesn't change anything about the UITableView so the table view appears cropped to 280*132.